# is there a way to add process_query_information to existing process handle?

Tags: c++, winapi, reverse-engineering, dll-injection

i'm absolute beginner to this, i've been trying to collect handle on my system using ntquerysysteminformation and now i get the handle that i want(i know this by using processhacker) but the problem coming when i try to collect the pid from that handle in order to determine which handle that is correct to inject my dll(my function returns array of handle), i know it can be simply use getprocessid() from msdn but it returns 0x6 errorcode.

is there another graceful way to do this without using openprocess?
*duplicatehandle() doesn't seems to work as well

or is there a way to simply add process_query_information access right to this handle?

Comment: Why are you trying to inject a dll into another program? And why is the question tagged `reverse-engineering`?

Comment: i want to inject my dll to implement the reversed version of that program inside that program

Comment: Reversed version? How and what program exactly?

Comment: for what you need **add** `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` ? if this access is need - just open handle with this access. *returns 0x6 errorcode* - mean invalid handle at all. you not show any code and your question\problem is unclear in current form

Comment: i need it to get the pid from retrieved handle, zwqueryinformationprocess doesnot work, however it will work if i use openprocess all access to the handle that i want the information to be retrieved, is there anyway to not use openprocess?

Comment: XY problem. Why not show code, intstead your proposed solution

Comment: *zwqueryinformationprocess doesnot work* what is mean *doesnot work* ?

Comment: How do you get the array of handle? Maybe you are using `NtQuerySystemInformation` with `SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS.SystemHandleInformation`(16). It will return an array size and a `SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION` array , which contains both `ProcessId` and `Handle` in each `SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION`.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT yes indeed, but my target process is a child process which it's parent have multiple processes so i do need to specify the target pid while SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION processid is pointing to the parent :( please help me i want to hack a game so i can spent my holiday with fun, and i hope u guys having fun looking me fun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we are in an external process, so it makes no sense to distribute the handle provided by `NtQuerySystemInformation`, you need to copy the handle into our own process.

source process for testing:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
   
    HANDLE hprocess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ,false,10924);//any access without PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION
    printf("pid: %d\n", GetCurrentProcessId());
    printf("handle:  0x%x\nwait...\n", hprocess);
    getchar();
    CloseHandle(hprocess);
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
pid: 11972
handle:  0x108
wait...
```

main process:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct _SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION
{
    ULONG ProcessId;
    UCHAR ObjectTypeNumber;
    UCHAR Flags;
    USHORT Handle;
    PVOID Object;
    ACCESS_MASK GrantedAccess;
}SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION, * PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION;

typedef struct _SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION_EX
{
    ULONG NumberOfHandles;
    SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION Information[655360];//This is the size I defined myself
}SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION_EX, * PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION_EX;

#define SystemHandleInformation 0x10

typedef NTSTATUS(WINAPI* NTQUERYSYSTEMINFORMATION)(DWORD, PVOID, DWORD, PDWORD);

int main()
{
    HMODULE hNtDll = LoadLibraryW(L"ntdll.dll");
    NTQUERYSYSTEMINFORMATION NtQuerySystemInformation = (NTQUERYSYSTEMINFORMATION)GetProcAddress(hNtDll, "NtQuerySystemInformation");
    ULONG cbBuffer = sizeof(SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION_EX);
    LPVOID pBuffer = (LPVOID)malloc(cbBuffer);
    if (pBuffer)
    {
        NTSTATUS  status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemHandleInformation, pBuffer, cbBuffer, NULL);
        PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION_EX pInfo = (PSYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION_EX)pBuffer;
        DWORD pid = 0;
        int err = 0;
        for (ULONG r = 0; r < pInfo->NumberOfHandles; r++)
        {
            if (pInfo->Information[r].ProcessId == 11972 && pInfo->Information[r].Handle == 0x108)//hard code to test
            {
                if ((pid = GetProcessId((HANDLE)pInfo->Information[r].Handle)) == 0)
                {
                    err = GetLastError();
                    cout << "The 1st GetProcessId error : " << err << endl;
                }
                HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, false, pInfo->Information[r].ProcessId);
                HANDLE hTarget;
                if (!DuplicateHandle(hProcess, (HANDLE)pInfo->Information[r].Handle, ::GetCurrentProcess(), &hTarget, PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, 0))
                {
                    err = GetLastError();
                    cout << "DuplicateHandle error : " << err << endl;
                    return -1;
                }
                if ((pid = GetProcessId(hTarget)) == 0)
                {
                    err = GetLastError();
                    cout << "GetProcessId error : " << err << endl;
                    return -1;
                }
                cout << "The 2nd GetProcessId succeed, " << "ProcessId =  " << pid << endl;
            }

        }

        free(pBuffer);
    }
    FreeModule(hNtDll);
    getchar();
}
```

Result:

```
The 1st GetProcessId error : 6
The 2nd GetProcessId succeed, ProcessId =  10924
```

Comment: Hi,@yami sukehiro, does the answer help to you? please feel free to  let me know if you have any question, or you could [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it if it does help.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i already done couple days ago, but my question is is there another way to do this without openprocess? Like simply by changing security context of a process or etc. If no then this answer was helpful thanks for that, case closed

Comment: Error 6 has nothing to do with whether you have process_query_information access permission. As I metioned, you need to copy the process handle to current process,otherwise it will not be recognized.

Comment: what is wrong with error 6 as it said that it was invalid handle error, but why i can open or duplicate that handle if it was an invalid handle?

Comment: Invalid handle is relative to the current process,`DuplicateHandle` will specify `hProcess`, this handle is valid for `hProcess`, and then duplicated it to current process.

Comment: and sorry for additional your code is actualy didn't work for my case because you didn't specify process_query_limited information on your duplicatehandle function but use duplicate_same_access instead, so i just changed the dwdesiredaccess parameter with process_query_limited_information so u can getprocessid on the duplicated handle

Comment: So you mean, the target original handle obtained by `NtQuerySystemInformation` does not have process_query_information permission in the target process as well?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea about NtQuerySystemInformation.SystemHandleInformation needs process_query_information access right if it does, the handle that i retrieved from that handle is correct according to process hacker(i am using this application for handle check)

Comment: so yes, that's what i'm trying to do is to gain process_query_information access rights to that handle without openprocess if it's possible

Comment: *your code is actualy didn't work for my case* Can you describe some details? I tested to specify PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, but GetProcessId can still be executed successfully, do you get any errorcode?

Comment: For what I mean “the target original handle” is, process A open a handle to process B with an access(xxx), then process C call NtQuerySystemInformation, does the xxx contains process_query_information when A open B? Anyway, I can get the process id by C, even the xxx doesn't contains `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` or `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION`.

Comment: it still execute indeed but it returns 0 according to msdn getprocessid returns 0 if function fails and it throws errorcode 5 from getlasterror function

Comment: More complicated, as you ask, add access to a handle(still need to duplicate from the source process),use [`SetSecurityInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-setsecurityinfo), refer to [this sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6808899/10611792) with `AddAccessAllowedAce` instead of `AddAccessDeniedAce`.

Comment: Man this helped me a lot thanks for your time, maybe should diving more into access control Model thing godbless u have a nice day sir o7

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (SYSTEM_HANDLE a : getAllProcessesHandle()) {
        if ((HANDLE)a.wValue == isthehandleiwant) {
            owner = OpenProcess(PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, false, a.dwProcessId);
            bool duplicatestatus = DuplicateHandle(owner, (HANDLE)a.wValue, GetCurrentProcess(), &duplicatedHandle, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS, false, 0);
            
        }                       
    }

std::cout << std::dec << GetProcessId(duplicatedHandle) << " TEST " << std::endl;
return duplicatedHandle;
```