# How to find out who killed the process?

Tags: c#, .net, process

I need to protect the process of my program. To do this, the closure I need to know what process caused the closure of the program (taskkill, FAR).
How to do it?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. You would have to somehow intercept a call to the Windows API function `TerminateProcess()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not prevent your process from being killed (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121746/prevent-c-sharp-app-from-process-kill) and [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/16/73780.aspx)) and there is no way to know who killed the process.

Comment: Interesting article. We can assume that the problem of application security to lie on the shoulders of the administrator?

Comment: I don't understand what "I want to prevent my program from being killed" has to do with "application security"? This is not about security at all.

Comment: There is a program that monitors the running applications, and does not run the program from the "black list." If my program can be turned off, what's the meaning of it?

Comment: Well, that's how things work. Instead of a program you can create a Windows service which is run be a privileged account. Then, only an admin account can kill the process. Other than that: Right - a program like the one you're about to create doesn't fully work :-)

Comment: But since Win 7 service do not have access to the windows, and I need to extract the name of some windows :(

Comment: Well, in that case the answer is: What you want can not be done. You could write a privileged service that monitors whether your program is running, however, and restart it if needed.

Comment: I'm going to look. Thank you for your time :)